# Can't figure out why importing numpy isn't working?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to import the numpy package in PyCharm by using

```
import numpy as np
```

but I keep getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/kaushikkolla/PycharmProjects/DataManipulation/main.py", line
> 1, in 
> import Numpy as np ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Numpy'

I checked in the python interpreter and I have the numpy package imported so I can't figure out how to solve this. Thanks

Comment: you have typo - traceback show that in your code numpy is with capital N, i.e. Numpy

Comment: It says `Numpy` with a capital N in the error message. Make sure you write `import numpy` with all lower case characters in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check again if Numpy module is installed. If not then run the below command in terminal to install.

```
pip install numpy
```

If this doesn't solve your issue refer the below official link of Numpy documentation for troubleshooting the import error.

[Troubleshooting Import Error - Numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html)

Answer (score -3):

As buran and G. Sliepen commented above, you should try writting "Numpy" instead of "numpy" in the import line. Also, if that doesn't help, which I doubt, you could run your CMD (if windows) and try the following command:

pip install --upgrade numpy